# How to Extend a logical volume in VMware

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have a CentOS 6.3 into my Virtual Machine.

I have 2 disks:

- Disk#1 = 18G
- Disk#2 = 20G

organized like this:

```
[root@supervision-rac ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_root
                     1008M  250M  708M  27% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             194M   31M  154M  17% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_home
                      504M   17M  462M   4% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_opt
                      2.0G   68M  1.9G   4% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg_produits-lv_grid
                      6.9G  2.5G  4.1G  38% /opt/grid
/dev/mapper/vg_produits-lv_oracle
                      6.9G  144M  6.4G   3% /opt/oracle
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_tmp
                      2.8G   71M  2.6G   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_usr
                      2.5G  1.6G  799M  67% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_var
                      2.0G  278M  1.6G  15% /var



[root@supervision-rac ~]# pvs
  PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_system   lvm2 a--  17.80g    0
  /dev/sdb1  vg_produits lvm2 a--  20.00g 6.00g
[root@supervision-rac ~]# vgs
  VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg_produits   1   2   0 wz--n- 20.00g 6.00g
  vg_system     1   7   0 wz--n- 17.80g    0
[root@supervision-rac ~]# lvs
  LV        VG          Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  lv_grid   vg_produits -wi-ao--   7.00g
  lv_oracle vg_produits -wi-ao--   7.00g
  lv_home   vg_system   -wi-ao-- 512.00m
  lv_opt    vg_system   -wi-ao--   2.00g
  lv_root   vg_system   -wi-ao--   1.00g
  lv_swap   vg_system   -wi-ao--   7.00g
  lv_tmp    vg_system   -wi-ao--   2.80g
  lv_usr    vg_system   -wi-ao--   2.50g
  lv_var    vg_system   -wi-ao--   2.00g
```

So i want to extend my /tmp and my /opt/oracle like this:

```
10Go in/tmp
13Go in /opt/oracle
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing `6.00g` as free size, you can't add 14g (10-2+13-6.9). Consider expanding your virtual disks or creating some new, and then you just `lvextend`.

Ok if it is a typo and the aritmethics solve, is the same, you can use `lvresize -r` with both partitions. You can boot a live Linux distribution and do those changes. If you do that **do not forget the `-r` thing**.

AFAICR and actually watching the output of my `lvresize --help`, guess the minimum calls for your case would seem to be like my usual `lvresize -L NU_SIZE -r LV_NAME` althought we do not use the same GNU/Linux distribution. But you have to e2fsck the volumes first. If you do not, in the worst case it will just safely fail.